# Validar con data anottation un checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo un formulario que contiene 9 `input` de tipo `checkbox` necesito validar que al enviar el formulario al menos uno de ellos venga tickeado.

Tengo lo siguiente en mi vista

```
<div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 li">
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.MiCheckViewModel.Institutions[0].Value)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.MiCheckViewModel.Institutions[0].Text)
    <label>
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.MiCheckViewModel.Institutions[0].Selected)
        <span class="title">@Model.MiCheckViewModel.Institutions[0].Text</span>
    </label>
</div>
```

En total tengo 9 campos de esta misma forma.

En mi modelo tengo lo siguiente

```
public class Input
{
    public Input()
    {
        this.MiSelectViewModel = new MiSelectViewModel();
        this.MiCheckViewModel = new MiCheckViewModel();
    }

    public MiSelectViewModel MiSelectViewModel { get; set; }
    public MiCheckViewModel MiCheckViewModel { get; set; }
}

public class MiSelectViewModel
{
    public List<SelectListItem> Institutions { get; set; }
    public List<int> SelectedInstitutions { get; set; }
}

public class MiCheckViewModel
{
    public List<SelectListItem> Institutions { get; set; }
    public List<int> SelectedInstitutions { get; set; }
}
```

¿Como puedo hacer esto de la forma correcta, para poder hacer la validacion desde el modelo de los campos que llegan desde la vista, usando los data anottation de ASP.NET MVC?

El problema principal es evitar que se mande el formulario sin tickear ningun checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar un script que valide la informacion ates de hacer el post

```
function myFunction() {
   var hayCheck;
   var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
   var checkBox2 = document.getElementById("myCheck2");
   var text = document.getElementById("text");
   if (checkBox.checked == true){
     haycheck=true;
   } else if(checkBox2.checked == true) {
     haycheck=true;
   }

   if(hayCkeck)
   {
     //Llamas El Post
   }else{
     //Muestras el Error
     text.html("Error")
}
```